# Capturar no JavaScript um option específicio

Tags: javascript, html

#### O Sistema:

Eu tenho um `select` com alguns option e sub-options (já explico). Esse `select` é gerado pelo php de acordo com as categorias que são cadastradas no banco de dados, ou seja, eu tenho a **CATEGORIA 01** mas nessa categoria eu cadastro uma subcategoria, então ela fica como **Subcategoria 01**, se eu cadastrar nessa subcategoria uma outra subcategoria, ela fica como **SubSubcategoria 01** e assim infinitamente.

Na geração do HTML,no `select`, todos eles vem como `option` *(não aninhado um dentro do outro como na UL > LI > UL > LI, etc)*.

O select fica assim:

```
<select id="selecao">
    <option value="cat1">Eletronicos</option>
        <option value="sec1">Informática</option>
            <option value="prod1">Monitores</option>
            <option value="prod2">Gabinetes</option>
    <option value="cat2">CATEGORIA 02</option>
</select>
```

Eu preciso capturar o value da categoria dos produtos, isto é, se eu clicar no `option`  **Monitores** a minha variavel no javascript vai capturar o value da categoria de produtos (São aqueles marcados como **cat1** e **cat2**)

EDIT:

#### Estrutura do banco de dados:

No banco eu tenho uma tabela que gravas as categorias, cada categoria tem um id, um parent_id e um depth

o parent_id diz à qual categoria pai ela está associada e o depth diz qual o nível da categoria

- Eletronico tem parent_id = null e depth = 0
- Informática é subcategoria de Eletronico  então tem parent_id = 1 (pq id de Eletronico no banco é 1) e depth = 1
- Monitores é subcategoria da subcategoria Informática e por isso tem parent_id = 10 (porque o id de Informática no banco de dados é 10) e depth = 2

Essa é a ideia de relacionamento das categorias na tabela.

Agradeço a todos que puderem ajudar.

Eu não achei pergunta similar que ajude a resolver esse problema, se você souber de alguma que vai me ajudar, marque aqui. Obrigado

Comment: E se o cara selecionar "Eletronicos" ou "Informática"?

Comment: Lougans, nessa forma em que todos estão no mesmo select será considerado como sendo "irmãos" sem diferentes níveis de parentescos. Como está sua estrutura no banco? e uma sugestão: que tal quebrar em vários selects, dependendo da categoria pai selecionada ele exibe outro select filho (se houver) associado aquele pai?

Comment: @Sam, A mesma coisa. As categorias principais são apresentadas em Uppercase e as subcategoria de forma normal. Esse espaçamento é como aparece na renderização do html por conta dos &nbsp; Eu quero ver um jeito que da pra fazer isso se tiver é claro. É pra evitar de ter que mudar toda o código que já foi escrito por outra pessoa hehe...

Comment: Então independente da opção marcada, você quer pegar cat1, cat2 etc..?

Comment: @Sam a ideia é gravar em uma variavel do javascript o valor das categorias principais cat1, cat2. Isso mesmo. Se eu clicar em Informática ou monitores ou qualquer outro que estiver dentro do "aninhamento" da categoria principal, ela vai capturar a cat1

Comment: @MatheusCristian eu editei minha pergunta colocando como é a estrutura e relacionamentos, ve se fiz sentido kkkk

Comment: Ah sim, deu pra entender melhor. Se você quer só pegar o nome da categoria, que tal você colocar no próprio value, ao invés de "prod1" ou "prod2" o "cat1" somente? colocar no value a própria categoria

Comment: @MatheusCristian isso tudo vai vir dinamicamente, certo? Eu dei exemplo com nome das categorias para exemplificar aqui, mas é claro que o value dessas categorias será um número, um id que vai referenciar lá no banco de dados, mas quero capturar pelo javascript, rsrs... Infelizmente esse código nao foi feito por mim inicialmente e queria resolver isso na estrutura atual do código (senão terei de mudar muita muita coisa), se nao for possível :/

Comment: Mas os values serão sempre assim nesse padrão: cat1, sec1, prod1, prod2, cat2 etc...?

Comment: @Sam eu disse no comentário ali para o Matheus que só coloquei esses nomes por carater de exemplo mesmo, hehe.. Os value serão todos números sem diferenciação entre eles, apenas um valor de auto-incremento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sem mexer no HTML não tem como fazer isso, porque você não tem nenhuma referência pra saber que um option é relacionado a outro anterior, porque são todos elementos irmãos. Você resolveria isso colocando apenas uma classe na option que representa uma categoria, por exemplo:

```
<select>
   <option class="cats" value="123">CATEGORIA 1</option>
   ... options da cat1
   <option class="cats" value="456">CATEGORIA 2</option>
   ... options da cat2
</select>
```

Com essa classe fica bem fácil pegar o `value` com JavaScript, fazendo um loop reverso. Basta pegar o índice do option selecionado e voltar até o primeiro option anterior que possua a classe `.cats`:

```js
document.getElementById("selecao").onchange = function(){
   var idx = this.selectedIndex;
   if(this.className != "cats"){
      
      for(var x = idx; x > -1; x--){
   
         var opt = this.querySelectorAll("option")[x];
   
         if(opt.className == "cats"){
            var categoria = opt.value;
            break;
         }
         
      }
      
   }else{
      
      var categoria = this.value;
      
   }

   console.log(categoria);
}
```

```html
<select id="selecao">
    <option class="cats" value="cat1">Eletronicos</option>
        <option value="sec1">Informática</option>
            <option value="prod1">Monitores</option>
            <option value="prod2">Gabinetes</option>
    <option class="cats" value="cat2">CATEGORIA 02</option>
        <option value="sec2">Informática</option>
            <option value="prod3">Monitores2</option>
            <option value="prod4">Gabinetes2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Fantástico, isso deu certo. Levei um tempinho para compreender todas as partes da função mas deu tudo certo. Fiz algumas alterações apenas e resolveu o problema. Muuito obrigado Sam. ^^

Comment: Esqueci de colocar a descrição do código, mas é bem fácil de entender. Valew!

Comment: Sim, bem fácil 
^^

Comment: se puder ver sobre esse problema meu aqui tambem, [Clique aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/369381/problemas-com-lista-de-categorias-produtos)