# Problemas com Lista de Categorias / Produtos

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho trabalho em cima de uma tela de produtos com categorias e subcategorias, porém tenho achado alguns problemas:

#### O  QUE QUERO FAZER:

Eu simplesmente quero ter uma página com a lista de produtos. Do lado irá ser exibido as categorias principais e as subcategorias disponíveis. Tendo visto isso. Já consegui listar e atualmente ele está exibindo os produtos corretamente mas é apenas quando eu clico na categoria específica, por exemplo:

**LISTA DE PRODUTOS**

- REVISTAS
  -- Isto é
  -- Veja
  -- Vogue
- HQ's
  -- DC
  -- Marvel

Tudo nessa lista são categorias: **Revistas**, **HQ's**, **DC**, **Veja**, etc. Todas elas devem ser como um filtro.

#### O QUE ESTÁ DANDO ERRADO:

A página de `produtos.php` possui a query que busca apenas os produtos da categoria específica, ou seja, se eu clicar na subcategoria **Marvel**, ela vai retornar os produtos que tem a categoria_id da categoria **Marvel**. Ok?
Mas se eu clicar em **REVISTAS** ou **HQ's** ela não vai retornar nada e eu quero retornar todos os produtos dela, isto é, se eu clicar em **REVISTAS** ela vai retornar todos os produtos (*Isto é, Veja e Vogue*), mas a página contém a query para retornar produtos específicos e não todos os produtos de uma categoria.

#### O QUE EU JÁ PENSEI EM FAZER:

Eu pensei em fazer talvez um `if/else` que validaria se a opção clicada fosse "**REVISTA/HQS**" e mudaria as instruções de consulta SQL mas mesmo assim não consegui concluir a lógica dela.

Eu vou deixar 2 coisas aqui: código da lista de categoria e o código da lista de produtos:

**Lista de Categorias:**

```
<aside class="content-category col-lg-3">
     <h3>Lista de Produtos</h3>
          <ul class="list-category">
                    <?php
                    $QueryCategorias = $db->Executar("SELECT * FROM pro_categorias WHERE adm_id= $adm_id AND excluido = 0 AND depth = 0 ORDER BY pro_cat_nome ASC");
                    while ($ListaCategorias = $QueryCategorias->fetch_object()):
                        $QuerySubCategorias = $db->Executar("SELECT * FROM pro_categorias WHERE adm_id = $adm_id AND excluido = 0 AND parent_id = $ListaCategorias->pro_cat_id");
                        ?>
                    <li class="cat-item">
                        <?= $ListaCategorias->pro_cat_nome; ?>
                        <?php if($QuerySubCategorias): ?>
                            <ul class="sublist-category">
                                <a href="<?= $tdir ?>/produtos/<?= $adm_id ?>/<?= $ListaCategorias->pro_cat_id ?>#produtos">
                                    Todos
                                </a>
                                <?php while ($ListaSubCategorias = $QuerySubCategorias->fetch_object()): ?>
                                    <li class="subcat-item">
                                        <a href="<?= $tdir ?>/produtos/<?= $adm_id ?>/<?= $ListaSubCategorias->pro_cat_id ?>#produtos">
                                            <?= $ListaSubCategorias->pro_cat_nome; ?>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                <?php endwhile; ?>
                            </ul>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </li>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </ul>
            </aside>
```

**Lista de Produtos:**

```
<div class="produtoWrapper">
          <?php /*PRODUTOS*/
                        $produtos = $db->Consultar("produto_pro", "pro_id, pro_nome, pro_descricao, pro_avatar", "WHERE adm_id = $adm_id AND categoria_id = $pro_cat_id AND excluido = 0 ORDER BY pro_nome");
                        if ($produtos) {
                            foreach ($produtos as $produto) {

                                if (isset($lista_prioridade) && in_array($produto['pro_id'], $lista_prioridade)) continue;

                                $thumbnail = returnThumbnailURL($Dominio, $produto['pro_avatar']);
                                $produto['pro_descricao'] = strip_tags($produto['pro_descricao']);
                                $produto_nome = $produto['pro_nome'];
                                if (sizeof($produto['pro_nome']) > 20) $produto_nome .= "...";
                                ?>

                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="thumbnail no-padding">
                                        <a href="<?= $tdir ?>/item/<?= $adm_id ?>/<?= $produto['pro_id'] ?>#item">
                                            <img src="<?= $thumbnail ?>" alt="<?= $produto_nome ?>">
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="produto-descricao">
                                            <p>
                                                <a href="<?= $tdir ?>/item/<?= $adm_id ?>/<?= $produto['pro_id'] ?>#item"><?= $produto_nome ?></a>
                                            </p>
                                            <!--<p class="small"><?= substr($produto['pro_descricao'], 0, 50); ?></p>-->
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <?php }
                        } ?>
</div
```

E outra coisa pra ajudar vocês a entenderem é a estrutura e relacionamento das tabelas envolvidas nisso:

#### Estrutura e Relacionamentos/Banco de dados:

No banco eu tenho uma tabela que gravas as categorias, cada categoria tem um `id`, um `parent_id` e um `depth`

o `parent_id` diz à qual categoria pai ela está associada e o `depth` diz qual o nível da categoria

- Eletronico tem parent_id = null e depth = 0
- Informática é subcategoria de Eletronico então tem parent_id = 1 (pq id de Eletronico no banco é 1) e depth = 1
- Monitores é subcategoria da subcategoria Informática e por isso tem parent_id = 10 (porque o id de Informática no banco de dados é 10) e depth = 2

Essa é a ideia de relacionamento das categorias na tabela.

Bom, era isso, preciso muito de ajuda pois já estou me batendo com isso ja faz algum tempo e já tentei algumas soluções mas nenhuma delas surtiu resultado.

Qualquer duvida é só comentar que respondo.

Grato!